# syntaxic highlighting in emacs with LaTeX French quotation

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, quote, font-lock

I would like to have syntaxic highlighting in emacs when I write LaTeX code in French.

More precisely, I want emacs to recognize when I'm quoting someone.

In english when you write :

```
``quote''
```

Emacs reconizes that it's a quotation and put "quote" in some color.

In French, quotation are made with the help of babel and looks like this :

```
\og quote\fg{}
```

I would like to color "quote" in the same way than in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX recognizes french latex files by this code fragment.

```
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
```

This will install french style quoting via key ', but no
font-lock support.  To add this, you can put

```
(add-hook 'TeX-language-fr-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-latex-add-quotes '("\\og" "\\fg{}")))))
```

in your init-file.

muede

Comment: Are you sure of the syntax ? I have a error when I put your code into my .emacs

Comment: Probablly because the variable is not defined ?  Have you tried this after loading AUCTeX ?

Comment: I have putted your lign at the end of my .emacs and auctex is launched before with `(load "auctex.el" nil t t)`.

Comment: @ppw, You need to load `font-latex` for this variable to be defined.

Comment: ok but could you show me an example. What do I have to add to my .emacs ?

Comment: I expanded on the answer.